# How to move controller configuration into its own file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following angular configuration in the file index.js:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url: '/entry',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/entry/entry.html',
                controller: 'EntryPageController'
            })


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/entry');
    }])

    .controller('EntryPageController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function () {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }])
```

I'm trying to move the controller definition (which works in the example above) into its own file, as follows:

```
// file name entry-ctrl.js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
        .controller('EntryPageController', ['$scope', '$state', EntryPageController]);

    function EntryPageController($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function () {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }
})
();
```

In index.html I've referenced the file as

```
<script src="app/views/entry/entry-ctrl.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, I can't get the application to behave correctly. When I use the original code, the page appears as I expect. But when I use the code in the entry-ctrl.js file, nothing appears.

Is there something else I need to do to use the code in the entry-ctrl.js file?

For the record, this is my entry.html:

```
<ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" class="bubble-background">
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <h1>I'm working!</h1>
        <a class="button button-positive" ng-click="signIn()" ui-sref="main.home">Sign In</a>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your `EntryPageController` definition over the `angular.module` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that you declared your angular app twice, once in `index.js` and in `entry-ctrl.js`.

I would change it to this:

**index.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url: '/entry',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/entry/entry.html',
                controller: 'EntryPageController'
            })


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/entry');
    }])
```

**entry-ctrl.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ionicApp')
        .controller('EntryPageController', ['$scope', '$state', EntryPageController]);

    function EntryPageController($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function () {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }
})();
```

---

in angular, you declare your app with an array of dependencies:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
```

and you reference it only by name:

```
angular.module('ionicApp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible that your Controller definition has to be above your module definition ?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // First, define your Controller
    function EntryPageController($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function () {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }

    // Then call it in your module
    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
        .controller('EntryPageController', ['$scope', '$state',    EntryPageController]);

})(this);
```